# Clojure function throws a null pointer exception

Tags: list, vector, clojure, nullpointerexception, arity

I've just begun to teach myself clojure and I'm having fun. However trouble began when I began to exec this function I wrote!

It's a simple function that accepts multiple number of arguments & returns the difference between the last and the first arguments.

```
(defn diff-last-first 
   "gets the difference between the last & the first arguments" 
   [& args] 
   (- (get args (- (count args) 1)) (get args 0)))
```

I know that I can simply use the **last** function to get the last element of args, but I'm not able to understand why this is throwing a **NullPointerException** when I execute
`(diff-last-first 1 2 3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(get (list :foo) 0)` evaluates to nil.

Lists are not supposed to be accessed by index: it is a common design decision in Clojure to prevent such inefficiencies.

Comment: But `(- (get args (- (count args) 1)) (get args 0))` does return the correct answer! Only when I put it in the expression of a function it is throwing **NPE**

Comment: Huh? Lists in Clojure aren't supposed to be accessed by index?

Comment: @RaghuKanchiraju - I guess you tried that expression with `args` bound to a vector (not a list!), in the REPL?

Comment: @vemv Yes! It was a vector (array)

Comment: @RaghuKanchiraju then there you have your answer :) just keep in mind that lists, arrays and vectors are different things in Clojure.

Comment: @Chiron Nope - that's why trying so returns nil (as per `getFrom` in clojure.lang.RT)

Comment: Regarding accessing lists by index -- `get` does not work because lists are not associative. That you have to use `nth` to access a seq by index should be a reminder that performance is linear.

Answer (score 3):

If you do want to access the nth value of a list, you can use `nth`:

```
(defn diff-last-first [& args]
   (- (nth args (dec (count args)))
      (nth args 0)))
```

But of course, as you pointed out in your question, it is more idiomatic to use `first` and `last`:

```
(defn diff-last-first [& args]
  (- (last args) 
     (first args)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Got it!

@vemv was right! [& args] is a list and hence `(get args 0)` returns **nil**

Whereas `(defn get-l-f [args] (- (get args (- (count args) 1)) (get args 0)))` works as expected as **args** is a vector here!